# Help with P-channel FET not turning off

Tags: mosfet, switches, pmos

The circuit consists of an NRF52840 MCU controlling the power to a CO<sub>2</sub> sensor. The output from the sensor goes to a buffer which then feeds it back to an analog input.

The MCU operates at 3.3 V while all the other elements are connected directly to a battery at 3.6 V.

In terms of functionality, the system is working. When the MCU's pin is set to low (sensor ON state), the FET conducts, powering the sensor and the buffer and the the analog input has the CO<sub>2</sub> measurement signal. When the pin is set to high (OFF state), the sensor is off and there is nothing at the analog output.

The problem is that at the OFF state, there is about 1 V at the transistor's drain, when it should be completely off. I can't measure right now since I don't have the parts yet, but any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: how did you measure 1V?   the impedance would be quite high if measured on analog in. I suggest a 10A FET is a poor choice and a PNP would be better for switching 32mA with low Vce.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the IO pin can’t go all the way to 3.6V, this could be a problem with a FET or a BJT.  One solution would be to add an n-channel or NPN to provide an open-drain or open-collector signal that can then be pulled up to 3.6V with a resistor, and use this signal to drive the p-channel FET.

Comment: Add a resistor in series with the Mosfet's gate forming a voltage divider.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Frog, I will try what you suggest as I was thinking it could be related to the 0.3V difference

Answer (score 2):

As @Frog said, when the output of your microcontroller is at 3.3V and the supply voltage is 3.6V, \$V_{GS}\$ for the MOSFET is 0.3V. So, the MOSFET is not completely cut off.

If your 3.3V is actually a bit less than 3.3V and/or your 3.6V is actually a bit above 3.6V (a fully charged LiPo battery?) then the situation is worse.

You need to add another switching devices, such as an NPN or NMOS transistor, that can be controlled by the microcontroller while allowing the PMOS gate to rise all the way to 3.6V.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make everything clear on my side, when the IO is high (3.3V), what's happening with the 0.3V difference from the pullup. Is it being dissipated via the clamping diodes?
If I set the pin to high-Z will the pull-up be enough to turn the circuit off?

Answer (score 1):

Many integrated circuits draw very little current when Vcc is less than about 1V. This may be a non-problem. Assuming that you are switching to save power, measure the current when the MOSFET is Off and see if it is acceptable.

If the current leakage is unacceptable, a diode in series with the GPIO should be enough to get Vgs closer to zero. If your 3.6V supply can be slightly higher, you could decrease the value of R1 to increase the diode voltage drop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNObG1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed what you mention about the current being very low.
I like the diode solution as I would only need to add 1 more component. Will test it when I get the components.